# update ONLY a row of a group of results with similar characteristics

Tags: php, mysql, select, distinct

Good day all,

let's assume that we have a table with values divided in groups and we want to alter ONLY a row for each group. let's make some examples this is the start situation:

```
ID   |   CODE   |  DEFAULT   
-----+----------+-----------
1    |   1234   |     0
2    |   1234   |     0
3    |   1234   |     0
4    |   5678   |     0
5    |   5678   |     0
6    |   7777   |     0
7    |   8888   |     0
8    |   8888   |     0
9    |   8888   |     0
```

and we want to update the `DEFAULT`, but only ONE time for each `CODE` :

```
ID   |   CODE   |  DEFAULT   
-----+----------+-----------
1    |   1234   |     0
2    |   1234   |     1
3    |   1234   |     0
4    |   5678   |     1
5    |   5678   |     0
6    |   7777   |     1
7    |   8888   |     0
8    |   8888   |     0
9    |   8888   |     1
```

it is not important which one we update, we want ONLY one for each `CODE`.

actually I can think only at a `SELECT DISTINCT` then, with a loop, take the `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` then, if there is a result, `UPDATE` but it is really a dirty solution... I'm sure it can be done with a single (or a couple) query...

any ideas?

Comment: You could do every update query seperate and add a LIMIT 1 at the end of the query (`UPDATE table SET DEFAULT=1 WHERE CODE=1234 LIMIT 1`) Wouldn't know how to do this in one go though.

Comment: `select top` is a SQL Server dialect. Are you sure you are working with MySQL?

Comment: yes, pretty sure, I simply mistaken that... read it like "limit 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN` on a subquery that returns one row for each code:

```
update yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select min(id) minId
  from yourtable
  group by code
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.minid
set t1.`default` = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77cfe/1)